# Highcharts x-axis parallel to y-axis

Tags: highcharts

Question 1: Can we create a bubble chart with x-axis aligned vertically and opposite to y-axis as in below image.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLun3.png)

Question 2: Dual y-axes are possible in highcharts but a series data can be associated to just one y-axis, is it possible to associate a data series with both y-axis? In other words, data points plotting will be in respect to 3 axis:   x-axis and dual y-axes.

Comment: 1. Use [yAxis.opposite](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.opposite) option to set the axis opposite. 2. You can link series to only one axis, but you can link one axis to another with [axis.linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo) option. Examples are in the links I pasted.

Comment: Question 1: fundamentally, no - the `x` and `y` axes represent the two-dimensional space on which the points are plotted. If you make them represent the same dimension, that space is no longer two-dimensional and therefore you can't plot anything on it.